# Fill the color in diamond shape to a specific height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a diamond shape with in which I can fill the color upto a specific height that I would pass as an attribute/variable.

[image: Expected result].

I made the diamond shape. I was thinking to fit it in a div with the same height and width. Then I could mask the fill of the square. But still it doesn't seem to be the relevant way.

```
<div class="diamond"></div>
```

```
.diamond {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}

.diamond:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn’t pass the height as a CSS variable rather than an attribute?

Comment: @AHaworth attribute works as well. I was just highlighting the fact that I need to pass some percentage explicitly to show the progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) and [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient) instead:

```
.diamond {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(220,175,9,1) 50%, rgba(133,133,133,1) 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);
  width: 180px; 
  height: 300px;
}
```

Otherwise you would have to calculate when one half fills up and start filling the other which is more complicated I think. Alternatively use SVG shapes but I still think `clip-path` is best solution in this case.

In order to change the current % of fill you only need to change the 50% of the `linear-gradient` in both places through JavaScript and you're done :)